# Correct pronoun for negating a complete list with "I don't care about any of ..."

Tags: pronouns

Which would be correct pronouns to replace [...] in the following sentence:

> This thing has A,B and C, but I don't care about any of [...]

Them? It? These? ...?

Comment: It depends what you're not caring about. If it is the possibilities A B and C, then _them_, or _these_ if you want to give more prominence to them. If it's the whole situation then _it_.